# Link work Items in TFS 2010 in Excel

Tags: tfs, agile

We are using TFS 2010 with the Agile 5.0 template. We often use Excel to work on the Product Backlog to edit the work items in an easy way (change story points, title etc.) But in order to link items we have to go back to TFS. I guess that Excel is not a good UI to link items, but we would like to explore if there even is the possibility?

Answer (score 2):

If you have selected in the spreadsheet any row containing a WI, it should possible to edit it's links with "Links and Attachments":
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Excel to link Work Items. You have to look for another way.

**EDIT**

There's indeed a way to link a given Work Item, but I thought the question was more about creating links relationships inside the table of Excel, the for **many** work items as user777375 talked about editing the product backlog query result.

There's no way to mass link Work Items the same way you would mass change the value of a given field for many Work Items.